# Extract last frame of an animation to a new single .blend

Tags: animation

I have an animation of 100 frames, lots of falling letters to a stack.
Now I want to "extract" the final frame to a completely new .blend file where every letter has the final position and no animation of 100 frames in it.
But how to do this? I'm using Blender 3.4.1.

(The letters,position,rotation,scaling and type (A-Z) are random generated by a script, they have physics to fall naturally. I start the script and want to use only the final frame.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your blend file.
Open it and select all your letters, go to object > rigid body > bake to keyframes, in the frame range type 1-100 (or which ever frame you want to work with) and click OK to bake.
It'll take a few seconds, then your simulation will have individual keyframes, with all letters selected, delete the keyframes 1-99, and move the 100th to frame 1, there you go.

Comment: The important thing is, you need a rigid body object to be selected as the active object (i.e. highlighted in brighter orange) - without an active object or if this is not a rigid body object, the bake function will be greyed out, like what @Atari800XL erroneously posted as answer.

Comment: Oh, by the way: why duplicate the blend file? Just bake the simulation to keyframes and save the file under a new name...

Comment: Duplicating just as a backup measure, since baking is a destructive process and the user can't go back to make changes (except undos obviously)

Comment: Yes, of course you're right - but then you could write this in very, very many answers here, everywhere when modifiers are applied or objects are changed in _Edit Mode_ etc. ;) Rigid bodies are often simulated quite fast - what would be worse is baking a complex Mantaflow sim that took ages and then accidentally hit the _Free All_ button - that can't be undone :D

Comment: One more thing - you don't have to delete 99 keyframes and move the last one to frame 1. Just go to frame 100 so this is the current state of the objects. Then simply delete all keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

With letters selected search for Rigid > **Apply Transformation**, than Rigid > **Remove**.

... or alternatively - you can select all letters, last select Plane and Join them (Ctrl+J) ... sure in case you don't care to result at a single object :)

Save as a version.